# How to join query_id & METADATA$ROW_ID in SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on tracking the changes in data along with few audit details like user who made the changes.

[Streams](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html) in Snowflake gives delta records details and few audit columns including **METADATA$ROW_ID**.

Another table i.e. information_schema.query_history contain query history details including query_id, user_name, DB name, schema name etc.

I am looking for a way so that I can join **query_id** & **METADATA$ROW_ID** so that I can find the user_name corresponding to each change in data.

any lead will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Neeraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `METADATA$ROW_ID` column in a stream uniquely identifies each row in the source table so that you can track its changes using the stream.

It isn't there to track *who* changed the data, rather it is used to track *how* the data changed.

To my knowledge Snowflake doesn't track who changed individual rows, this is something you would have to build into your application yourself - by having a column like `updated_by` for example.

Comment: Thanks @SimonD for clarifying the use of ROW_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Only way i have found is to add

```
SELECT * FROM table(information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION()) ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

during reports / table / row generation

Assuming that you have not changed setting that you can run more queries at same time in one session , that gets running querys id's , change it to CTE and do cross join to in last part of select to insert it to all rows.

This way you get all variables in query_history table. Also remember that snowflake does keep SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY ( and other data ) up to one year. So i recommend weekly/monthly job which merges data into long term history table. That way you an also handle access to history data much more easier that giving accountadmin role to users.